# Python Selenium Webdriver: finding #document element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have been using Python's Selenium Webdriver getting elements with this HTML code.
However, I could not access any of the elements inside this #document tag.

I used both 
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/div[@id='frame']/iframe/*")`, and I tried 
`elem = driver.find_element_by_tag("iframe")`, following by 
`elem.find_element_by_xpath` to find inner elements but failed.

I also tried to do `driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag("iframe"))`, following with xpath expressions to find inner elements, but it also did not work.

Frame:

```
<div>
    <iframe>
        #document
            <html>
               <body>
                   <div>
                    ....   
                   </div>
               </body>
            </html>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Switching to the iframe and then using the normal query methods is the correct approach to use. I use it successfully throughout a large test suite.

Remember to switch back to the default content when you've finished working inside the iframe though.

Now, to solve your problem. How are you serving the contents of the iframe? Have you literally just written the html and saved it to a file or are you looking at an example site. You might find that the iframe doesn't actually contain the content you expect. Try this.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

b = Firefox()
b.get('localhost:8000') # or wherever you are serving this html from
iframe = b.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe')
b.switch_to_frame(iframe)
print b.page_source
```

That will be the html inside the iframe. Is the contents what you expect? Or is it mainly empty. If it's empty then I suspect it's because you need to serve the contents of the iframe separately.

Answer (score 0):

Web application developers are not very fond of iframes in general. As per their suggestion, I added a 'wait' time using Expected Conditions . After that you can fetch values of your tags. Here I have mentioned as val1.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
.... #some  code
.... #some  code
wait(driver, 60).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="iframeid"]')))

.... #some code
.... #some code

val1 = wait(browser, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//tr[(@cid="1")]/td[@ret="2" and @c="21"]')))
```

Hope this helps !